# Objective-C - ARC - NSNumber - Segmentation Fault

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, automatic-ref-counting, nsnumber, weak-references

I have an objective-C program and I am using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), it throws a segmentation fault in line 23 (see program below).

**Question**
1) Why does the segmentation fault occur ?

**Given below is the program:**

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
@property (weak) NSNumber* doors;
@end

@implementation Car 
@synthesize doors;
@end

int main()
{
    system("clear");

    @autoreleasepool
    {    
        Car *car1 = [[Car alloc] init];

        printf("1\n");
        NSNumber *d1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 4]; 

        printf("2\n");
        car1.doors = d1;   //Segmentation fault.. why ?

        printf("3\n");
    }   

    printf("---- end\n");

    return(0);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: This gives KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS, looks like a bus error rather than segmentation fault.

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you are using printf() instead of NSLog()?

Comment: I am just new to objective-C and so I tend to use printf

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Congratulations: you’ve found a bug in Core Foundation!

As Bill suspected, this is related to [tagged pointers in Lion](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in). When you create

```
NSNumber *d1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 4];
```

`d1` doesn’t point to an actual `NSNumber` instance. Instead, `d1` is a tagged pointer containing `0x4c3`, where `0x4` is the payload in the tagged pointer.

When you try to use a tagged pointer as the value of a weak property, one of the steps executed by the Objective-C runtime is to send `-allowsWeakReference` to the instance to verify whether it can be used as a weak reference. Since `NSNumber` doesn’t override that method, the default implementation in `NSObject` is executed, which in turn sends `_isDeallocating`, which in turn calls `_CFIsDeallocating()` as shown in this stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007fff8ccdbacd in _CFIsDeallocating ()
#1  0x00007fff8ccd3119 in -[__NSCFNumber _isDeallocating] ()
#2  0x00007fff8be34b15 in -[NSObject(NSObject) allowsWeakReference] ()
#3  0x0000000100000ded in main () at test.m:12
```

If you read [CFRuntime.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFRuntime.c), you’ll see that `_CFIsDeallocating()` casts the corresponding pointer to `CFRuntimeBase *` in order to read `_cfinfo`. For normal Core Foundation objects, this works because every regular Core Foundation reference points to an instance that starts with the `isa` pointer, followed by `_cfinfo`. However, tagged pointers do not point to actual (allocated) memory, so `_CFIsDeallocating()` tries to dereference a pointer that is not valid, hence the segmentation fault.

You should [file a bug report with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com). In the meanwhile, use a `strong` or `unsafe_unretained` property.

---

**Edit:** to get the backtrace, build your executable with `-g` to include debug information, e.g.:

```
$ clang test.m -g -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -o test
```

and run it with GDB:

```
$ gdb test
…
(gdb) run
```

The program will crash:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000000000004cb
0x00007fff8ccdbacd in _CFIsDeallocating ()
```

Use the `bt` command in GDB to get the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8ccdbacd in _CFIsDeallocating ()
#1  0x00007fff8ccd3119 in -[__NSCFNumber _isDeallocating] ()
#2  0x00007fff8be34b15 in -[NSObject(NSObject) allowsWeakReference] ()
#3  0x00007fff875173a6 in weak_register_no_lock ()
#4  0x00007fff875179f9 in objc_storeWeak ()
#5  0x0000000100000c0e in -[Car setDoors:] (self=0x100113f60, _cmd=0x100000e7a, doors=0x4c3) at test.m:8
#6  0x0000000100000d45 in main () at test.m:23
```

and then the `quit` command to exit GDB:

```
(gdb) quit
```

In Xcode, use the Mac OS X > Application > Command Line Tool template. When you run your program, Xcode should automatically show the GDB prompt in the debug area. If the debug area doesn’t show up in the Standard Editor, select View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area.

---

**Edit:** this bug was fixed in OS X v10.7.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, it was very helpful and detailed explanation.

Comment: Nice debugging work... thanks for pursuing this and, yes, please DO file a bug.  I suspect it is a dupe, but... just in case...

Comment: How do I print the trace (clang-ARC) ? I am using it from command line. I would like to know how I can print the trace on command line and when I use X-Code what should I do ?

Comment: I somehow couldn't login into the apple link you had provided earlier to report the bug

Comment: You need a registered developer account (either free or paid). The bug reporting Web site has been flaky these past few days, though, so keep trying!

Comment: Just came across this as well and wish I'd just searched on here before coming to the same conclusion! +1 for an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Post the backtrace.  Also -- what platform?

It might be a bug related to `NSNumber` and tagged pointers (if targeting 64 bit OS X).

Comment: I just tried this myself, it's crashing inside `_CFIsDeallocating()`. I was thinking it looks like a bug with tagged pointers as well.